# Why is dummy node changing in this linked-list problem? (python3)

Tags: python

I've read several explanations & watched 6 YouTube videos and still don't understand what's going on in the solution to [this leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/merge-two-sorted-lists/). Can someone explain the relationship between dummy and cur & also dummy and cur.next-- in the simplest terms possible? Specifically, I'm confused on the following:

This is the code I'm referring to (I included a bunch of print statements to try to understand what lines of code are causing dummy to change).

```
   cur = dummy = ListNode()
    iteration=1
    while list1 and list2:
        print("\n iteration=", iteration)
        print("list1.val & list2.val=",list1.val," & ",list2.val)
        print("****dummy=",dummy)

        if list1.val < list2.val:
            print("\n first block")
            cur.next = list1
            print("cur.next=",cur.next)
            print("****dummy=",dummy)
            list1, cur = list1.next, list1
            print("list1 & cur=",list1, " & \n", cur)
            print("****dummy=",dummy)
        else:
            print("\n second block")
            cur.next = list2 #cur.next=something --> dummy.next=something
            print("cur.next=", cur.next)
            print("****dummy=",dummy)
            list2, cur = list2.next, list2 #cur=something does not change dummy
            print("list2 & cur=",list2, " & \n ", cur)
            print("****dummy=",dummy)

        if list1 or list2:
            print("\n third block")
            cur.next = list1 if list1 else list2
            print("cur.next=",cur.next)
            print("****dummy=",dummy)



        iteration+=1
    print("\n cur=",cur)
    print("****dummy=",dummy)

    return dummy.next
```

This is the output for the first iteration:

```
iteration= 1
list1.val & list2.val= 1  &  1
****dummy= ListNode{val: 0, next: None}

 second block
cur.next= ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
****dummy= ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}
list2 & cur= ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}  &
  ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
****dummy= ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 3, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}

 third block
cur.next= ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}
****dummy= ListNode{val: 0, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 1, next: ListNode{val: 2, next: ListNode{val: 4, next: None}}}}}
```

Okay, so what I noticed from above, in the second block: `cur.next=something`, sets `dummy.next=something`. But then, `cur=something`, does not set dummy=something. Why is this?
Then, in the third block, `cur.next=something` sets `dummy.next.next =something` (the something is linked to 0,1 instead of 0 as it was in the second block. Why is this?
Overall, I'm just pretty confused on the whole "pointer" thing and can't understand how `cur` & `cur.next` are related to `dummy` & `dummy.next` & `dummy.next.next` and so on.

Comment: There's really not that much into it. `cur = dummy = ListNode()` makes `cur` and `dummy` to reference the exact same object. It would be enough to add `print(id(cur), id(dummy))` to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea for this problem is to create a "sentinel" node which corresponds to `dummy`. This will be a "dummy" node representing the head of a new linked list that will be the "resultant" linked list constructed after performing the merge.

```py
# sentinel node
dummy = ListNode(-1)

# visual of `dummy` linked list
-1 -> None
```

The variable `cur` is simply a pointer to the "head" of the dummy linked list which we will use to insert new nodes while merging `list1` and `list2`. Using `cur.next = some_node` represents inserting a new node after `cur` in the dummy linked list.

```py
# sentinel node
dummy = ListNode(-1)

# pointer to head of "dummy" linked list
cur = dummy

# both dummy and cur are positioned at the "head" node with value -1
-1 -> None

# inserting a new node to the "dummy" list would look like
cur.next = ListNode(2)

# cur = dummy at this point so cur is still at the first node -1
# the linked list would have 2 nodes and cur.next equals node 2
dummy
cur
-1 -> 2 -> None

# since cur is still at the "dummy" node equaling -1, we want to move `cur`
# to the newly inserted node, this allows `cur` to be ready 
# for another insertion at the correct position in the linked list
cur = cur.next

dummy  cur
-1   -> 2 -> None

# dummy.next would represent a linked list with a single node 2
2 -> None
```

Below is an iterative approach similar to your logic with comments to better illustrate how we insert nodes into the "dummy" linked list using `cur` and continue moving the `list1` and `list2` node pointers as we iterate the two linked lists:

```py
# list1=[1,2,4]
# list2=[1,3,4]

# O(n+m) time and O(1) space
def mergeTwoLists(list1: Optional[ListNode], list2: Optional[ListNode]) -> Optional[ListNode]:
    # create a "dummy" node to represent 
    # resultant merged linked list
    dummy = ListNode(-1)

    # place cur pointer at head of dummy linked list
    cur = dummy

    # iterate both linked lists
    while list1 and list2:

        if list1.val <= list2.val:
            # insert node into the dummy list by updating
            # the "next" reference of `cur` to equal list1 node
            cur.next = list1

            # continue moving the list1 node to the "next" node in list1
            list1 = list1.next
        else:
            # insert node into the dummy list by updating
            # the "next" reference of `cur` to equal list2 node
            cur.next = list2

            # continue moving the list2 node to the "next" node in list2
            list2 = list2.next
        
        # keep moving the cur pointer as we insert to the dummy list
        cur = cur.next

    # there can be one value left to merge from one of the
    # two lists so insert the final node to complete the merge
    cur.next = list1 or list2

    # return dummy.next which skips the `dummy` node -1 and 
    # points to the new "head" of resultant merged list
    # -1 -> 1 -> 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 4 
    return dummy.next
```

Comment: Thanks! The one thing I still don't completely understand is why curr.next = something changes dummy, but curr=something does not change dummy.

Comment: No problem! The reason why `curr.next = new_node` changes dummy is because we are inserting a new node into the linked list represented by dummy. Where curr=new_node changes `dummy` but means we are replacing curr with new_node, instead of actually inserting a new node into the "next" node from curr. Imagine a chain-link wire, using curr.next=new_node adds a new node to the end of the chain, where curr=new_node would replace the current node in the chain without adding to it. `dummy` represents the first node in the chain and dummy never moves, just gets nodes added to its tail.

Answer (score 1):

The `=` operator between objects in Python results in both variable names referencing the same object in memory. Initially, `cur` and `dummy` refer to the same `ListNode` object, as opposed to `cur` being a different `ListNode` object with the same values. Therefore changes made to either will affect the other. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/assignment-shallow-or-deep-a-story-about-pythons-memory-management-b8fad87bfa6c) explains assignment vs shallow copy vs deep copy in Python.

When you reassign `cur` to `list1` the link between `cur` and `dummy` is gone.

EDITED: corrected mention of shallow copy for talking in terms of references, subject to comments.

Comment: I think your explanation is partly right, but saying that assignment is a shallow copy is generally wrong. There's no copy at all being done for most assignments.

Comment: I suppose it's more accurate to talk in terms of references like you would in C/C++. So the assignment operator results in both variable names referencing the same object in memory.

Comment: See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Comment: If the "link between cur and dummy is gone" after you reassign cur to list 1, then why does dummy keep changing after that when you assign curr.next to something?

Comment: dummy isn't really being changed after this (not due to shared references anyways), however, because of the line `cur.next = list2`, `dummy.next = list2` also, so changes to cur and list2 will affect dummy because `dummy.next` is linked

Answer (score 1):

`curr` and `dummy` are used to reference to same node (`listNode`), now `curr` is modified (ie a node from any of two linked list is referenced) and the node that it reference to is  referencing another node and so on . now the state of curr is different that what it used to be earlier at  creation (ie it reference to `None` as all merging is done) while `dummy` still referencing to first `node` only.

thus we can with the help of this `dummy` can get all the nodes these are referencing to , ie a merged linked list

`dummy.next` is used to get the first node of resultant linked list from the current linked list(having dummy as head node)